# how to create basic sku load balancer in YAML on Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

By default the SKU used when creating a load balancer in AKS is standard, for development if you want to use basic SKU we have to use the command line `az aks create -g RGName -n ClusterName --load-balancer-sku basic`

But could not find anything on how to specify the `--load-balancer-sku` in the yaml file.
Current YAML File AS-IS given below, what to add to make the SKU basic?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world-svc
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the SKU per ENV with passing a config file to the Cloud Controller Manager as of [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/cloud-provider-azure/topics/loadbalancer/#loadbalancer-skus)